# Made styled span into an Emoji component and I get warnings for not wrapping the emoji in a span. How does this work?

Tags: reactjs, components

According to the warning the way I did it is not ideal out of accessibility perspective. But how should it be done better, there is a role, aria-label and span in the component. How do I make it right?

One of the components creating a warning:

```
 <span
      type='button'
      onClick={() => setShowShoppingList(!showShoppingList)}>
        <Emoji ariaLabel="arrow-down">↓</Emoji> Reasons to Celebrate <Emoji ariaLabel="champagne-bottle"></Emoji>
    </span>
```

The styled component component  :
    import styled from "styled-components"

```
export const Emoji = styled.span.attrs(({ariaLabel}) =>({
    role: "img",
    "aria-label": ariaLabel,
}))`
    font-size: 50px;
`
```

The warning:
  Line 23:74:  Emojis should be wrapped in , have role="img", and have an accessible description with aria-label or aria-labelledby  jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji
  Line 31:13:  Emojis should be wrapped in , have role="img", and have an accessible description with aria-label or aria-labelledby  jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

For example:

```
<span role="img" aria-label="Lion face">&#129409;</span>
```

With the above method, you wouldn't get an error message.